# Using iOS loadNibName to retrieve subclass of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nib, retain

I have a UITableView filled with cells from a NIB-based subclass of UITableViewCell. I obtain each one like this:

```
+(id) getClassObjectFromNib:(NSString*) nibName subclassOf: (Class) cls owner:(id)own
{
    id result = nil;
    NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                loadNibNamed:nibName
                owner:own
                options:nil];
    for ( id currentObject in topLevelObjects )
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:cls]) 
        {
            result = currentObject;
            [result retain];
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

My call looks like:

```
@interface TargetViewController : UITableViewController 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [TargetCell defaultReuseIdentifier]; 
    TargetCell* cell = (TargetCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (TargetCell*) [UtilityHelper getClassObjectFromNib:CellIdentifier subclassOf:[UITableViewCell class] owner:self];
    }
    if ( nil != cell )
    {
        // Other initialization code for cell controls
        cell.showsReorderControl = 1;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But 'dealloc' never gets called on the cells when their view unloads.  If I remove the 'retain' above, dealloc gets called, but the app crashes when a cell is deleted individually (via swipe) from the UITableView (crash due to message to deleted item).

Except for the single deletion case, releasing the items occurs property when the view unloads.  The crash is  "-[TargetCell _setDeleteAnimationInProgress:]: message sent to deallocated instance".

Comment: Please add example where you use this method. Please also add interface of the object passed as `owner`

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using ARC? I recommend you use it, and then it depend how you store it in the instance that call your function.

Comment: Updated to add usage example.

Comment: I don't know ARC, and the core app was written before it was available. It appears that I'd have some substantial changes to make in transitioning.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem was due to reloading the table view as part of the row deletion operation (in **commitEditingStyle**).

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

This appears to work for standard **UITableViewCells** but does not work when the cell is a subclass loaded from an **XIB**.  Now I just alter the data source, delete the row (using **deleteRowsAtIndexPaths**) and return.